# angular2, php with mysql

Tags: php, angular, http

Hello everybody I've a problem to fetch the object json returned by the PHP Script.

When the server return the object json and I recover the object in angular I get this error. If I remove from the code the json convertion res.json() this error desapear and the server response is empty.

```
ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.webpackJsonp.../../../http/@angular/http.es5.js.Body.json (http.es5.js:797)
at SafeSubscriber._next (list-alunos.component.ts:14)
at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
```

I've a service that recover the information and a component that use this service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ApiHttpDaoService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public getListStudents() {
        return this.http.get("http://localhost/obtener_alunos.php");
    }
}
```

This is the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiHttpDaoService } from '../../services/api-http-dao.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-list-alunos',
    templateUrl: './list-alunos.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list-alunos.component.css']
})
export class ListAlunosComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private service: ApiHttpDaoService) {
        this.service.getListStudents().subscribe(
            res => console.log(res.json())
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

And this is the PHP file that return a json object:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    require("conectar_mysql.php");

    $vec_res = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM alunos");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            array_push($vec_res, array('nome' => $row['nome'], 'idade' => 
            $row['idade'], 'morada' => $row['morada']));
        }
        echo json_encode($vec_res);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: well what do you see in your network tab, what is actually being received? At least you are not receiving JSON. PS. also your `else` in PHP script will not return valid json, so is that what you might actually now receiving?

Comment: because response is not a valid json.

Comment: Well **what** are you actually receiving? I asked you to check your network tab and tell us. And if your php script goes to `else` it's not returning JSON, see: `echo "0 results";` which you edited away ;)

Comment: Hello I delete from my code the else but I have the same error. The else code never was executed

Comment: Can you please tell us what data you are receiving? Asking for the third time :D

Comment: Hello, I'm not receiving anything. I've check in the netowork but the body is empty.

Comment: Okay, if you see the request and the response is empty, then you need to check your php script and connection and everything on the backend. Your code looks correct to me and I tried it in my project just now. Just made the appropriate changes for the sql query and name of the data properties, but otherwise exactly your code and it worked fine for me. You need to debug your php script and query and actually see if it is executed correctly.

Comment: Okay but the json_enconde return something in the network in your test?? Thank you

Comment: There must be something going on there why you are getting empty response. Btw, there isnt any problem with your angular code either, and since the request is sent fine, but the result is empty we can conclude that it must be a backend problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the `Content-type` header twice. Get rid of the second one, `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: Thank you I have removed that line from the code but the error continue

Answer (score -1):

U need map ur request:

```
public getListStudents() {
    return this.http.get("http://localhost/obtener_alunos.php")
       .map(res => {return res;})
}
```

Comment: map(res => return res) is a no op

Comment: no operation; the map function is doing nothing in this case.

Comment: why? get url return nothing?

Comment: It's observable

Comment: map should always apply a transformation function to the values emitted by the observable. In this case, your transformation is the identity function (mathematically y = x). So, that line is useless.

Comment: ok, You right, but he can use this transformation, like "return res.json()"

Comment: better: map(r => r.json())